# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault (program runs out of stack.)

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault

I get this error message when i run the program with gdb. The error is shown at this line:

```
long a = thread_fake(); //in file1.c
```

I was getting the problem with other function that was defined in a separate file, so i simplified it to a simple function that just returns 0.
The function has been defined as:

```
long thread_fake(){ //defined in file2.c
    return 0;
}
```

As @EmployedRussian pointed out, it seems the program runs out of stack. The valgrind shows the following error:

```
==14711== 144 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 17 of 32
==14711==    at 0x4025315: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==14711==    by 0x4010CD7: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:300)
==14711==    by 0x401146B: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:464)
==14711==    by 0x40475C6: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1 (allocatestack.c:570)
==14711==    by 0x8050583: tm_main_startup 
==14711==    by 0x8048F6B: main (genome.c:201)
==14711== 144 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 18 of 32
==14711==    at 0x4025315: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==14711==    by 0x4010CD7: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:300)
==14711==    by 0x401146B: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:464)
==14711==    by 0x40475C6: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1 (allocatestack.c:570)
==14711==    by 0x804DFE3: thread_startup (thread.c:151)
==14711==    by 0x8048F73: main (genome.c:203)
```

All the threads created are joined a corresponding pthread_join call. Also i tried the sgcheck tool but it doesn't work on the platform'x86-linux'. Please help.

The complete output of bt command:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x406e8b70 (LWP 19416)]
sequencer_run (argPtr=0x89fce00) at sequencer.c:251
251 a = thread_fake();
(gdb) bt
#0  sequencer_run (argPtr=0x89fce00) at sequencer.c:251
#1  0x0804e306 in threadWait (argPtr=0x89dc1f4) at ../lib/thread.c:105
#2  0x4003be99 in start_thread (arg=0x406e8b70) at pthread_create.c:304
#3  0x40253cbe in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:130
```

Comment: Have you declared the function in file1.c or in a header file included by it?

Comment: @n.m. in a header file file2.h that is included by file1.c

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin no..

Comment: No repro and nothing I see immediately, unless you forgot to declare the function. There's something you're omitting. Turn on all warnings (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and show us the whole command line you use for compiling.

Comment: @GradyPlayer No.No linker warnings..

Comment: You write that you get this error when running the program with gdb. Does it occur when you're running it outside of gdb?

Comment: Post the shortest, complete, compilable example that you can which reproduces the error.

Comment: Sounds like could be a stack/memory corruption issue, when the problem moves around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error is shown at this line:
>
> `long a = thread_fake(); //in file1.c`

The likely way this could case a `SIGSEGV` is if your program has run out of stack.

Examine actual crashing instruction in GDB with `x/i $pc`.

If the instruction is a `PUSH`, or a `CALL`, then my guess is confirmed.

Another possibility: you've compiled your code with optimization, and the actual faulting instruction has little to do with the source line it is attributed to.

*Update:*

> Yes it gives a call `call 0x804e580 <thread_fake>`. What could be the solution?

The solution is to not run out of stack. Execute a GDB `where` command, then, in each frame leading to the crash, execute `info frame` and look for frames that are excessively large.

Don't allocate too much data on stack, or increase your stack size (`ulimit -s`).

> valgrind shows the following error:

That is

- not an error
- has nothing to do with your problem

*Update2:*

> How do I check the size of each frame?

Given this:

```
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffc248:
...
Stack level 1, frame at 0xffffc250:
...
Stack level 2, frame at 0xffffc2a0:
```

the size of frame #1 is `8` (`0xffffc250 - 0xffffc248`), frame #2 is `80`, etc.

**Final Update:**

It turned out that my procedure above failed to measure the size of frame#0, which turned out to be ... 61MB! due to presence of *humongous* local arrays (just as Grady Player correctly guessed).

Comment: that is a good possibility... the op should look for something like int huge[23456678899]; and not do that anymore.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes it gives a call "call 0x804e580 <thread_fake>" What could be the solution?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Also one more thing i would like to mention is that the program runs fine with single thread, but ends up with SIGSEGV on 2 or more threads..

Comment: @EmployedRussian i also checked with the commands where and info frame. But how do i check the size of each frame. It just mentions like-   Stack level 0, frame at 0x406e8370:
 eip = 0x8049a3c in sequencer_run (sequencer.c:251); saved eip 0x804e476  
 called by frame at 0x406e8390
 source language c.  
 Arglist at 0x406e8368, args: argPtr=0x89fde00
 Locals at 0x406e8368, Previous frame's sp is 0x406e8370
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0x406e835c, ebp at 0x406e8368, esi at 0x406e8360, edi at 0x406e8364,
  eip at 0x406e836c

Comment: @EmployedRussian From the info provided by i you, i get- 1) Stack level 0, frame at 0x406e8370;  called by frame at 0x406e8390   2) Stack frame at 0x406e8390: called by frame at 0x406e8490, caller of frame at 0x406e8370    3) Stack frame at 0x406e8490: called by frame at 0x0, caller of frame at 0x406e8390          So from this info, i conclude that there are 3 frames , first one starting at 0x406e8490 of size 256(8490-8390), second staring at 0x406e8390 of size 32(8390-8370), and third one starting at 0x406e8370, whose size is not known. Please correct me if i am wrong. So is 256 too large?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Moreover how much large is said to be too large?

Comment: @ceedee No, 256 is *not* too large (unless your thread stack is absurdly small). Please edit your question to show complete output of GDB `bt` command.

Comment: @ceedee So you are running out of stack almost immediately, without having consumed hardly any stack space. How exactly do you create this thread?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37364/discussion-between-ceedee-and-employed-russian)