# SIGSEGV Segmentation faul when trying to get a sub string

Tags: c, substring

I am getting the following error:

> Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation faul

The code is as follows:

```
int extraercadena(char *cad, char *tCad, int ini, int fin){
    int iC, iS;

    if ((ini>fin) || (ini < 0) || (fin >= strlen(cad)))
        return 0;

    iS = 0;

    for(iC = ini; iC <= fin; iC++){
        //error is here, the system halt here
        tCad[iS] = cad[iC];
        iS++;
    }

    tCad[iS] = '\0';

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault (program runs out of stack.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751532/program-received-signal-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-program-runs-out-of-stack)

Answer (score 1):

There are seven possibilities:

- `cad` can't be dereferenced because it's uninitialized or NULL or otherwise an invalid pointer.
- `iC` is negative.
- `cad` doesn't point to an array with at least `iC+1` elements.
- `tCad` can't be dereferenced because it's uninitialized or NULL or otherwise an invalid pointer.
- `tCad` doesn't point to an array with at least `iS+1` elements.
- `tCad` points to memory that isn't writable. (e.g. The memory returned by a string literal is usually read-only when possible.)
- It's the result of some other undefined behaviour in the program. (Not likely.)